# crontab steps plus increment

Tags: linux, cron

I want to issue two commands, c1 and c2, both every five minutes, but not at the same time, e.g.

```
0,5,10,15,20,... * * * * c1
2,7,12,17,22,... * * * * c2
```

is there a more elegant version using an asterisk instead of listing the numbers for c2?

Answer (score 6):

Something like this will do the job:

```
*/5     * * * * c1
2-59/5  * * * * c2
```

The first command (`c1`) will run at 0, 5, 10, 15, etc.
The second command (`c2`) will run at 2, 7, 12, 17, etc.

This may not work with all versions of cron.